# Install GitHub for Windows through proxy

Tags: windows, installation, proxy, github

I'm trying to install [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/). The problem is that I'm working through a proxy and the installation app don't let you change proxy settings.

Is there a workaround to change the proxy settings? And if not, is there a full installation version to download?

Comment: For an older version they said to modify `C:\Documents & Settings\<yourusername>\.gitconfig` with `[http]
proxy = http://dumbproxy.yourcompany.com:8080

[https]
proxy = http://dumbproxy.yourcompany.com:8080` or whatever is your proxy name

Comment: Is there a way to set username/password with that workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for old versions it was suggested to set the'.gitconfig' file that you can find in windows under `C:\Documents & Settings\<yourusername>\.gitconfig` (or however in %USERPROFILE%), those lines

```
[http]
    proxy = http://<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>

[https]
    proxy = https://<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<proxy port>
```

Note that in this way **you will leave your username and password in plain text**, without any encryption or protection...